# Does the library multprocesing works on sagemaker conda-python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, amazon-sagemaker

Does the library multprocesing works well on sagemaker conda-python3?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly depends on which use-case you have in mind, but typically for parallel processing of functions with `pool` from `multiprocessing` it works well and I use it regularly. For example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

# f is your function and L the list of items you want to apply f to
result = pool.map(f, L)
pool.quit()
pool.join()
```